# Reducer issues after updating to Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am receiving the following error when I compile my app. I'm not sure exactly what it means. I'm fairly new to angular, and I'm trying to update some legacy code to a new version of angular. Any direction would be very greatly appreciated.

```
    src/app/app.module.ts:30:9 - error TS2322: Type '{ app: typeof AppState; }' is not 
    assignable to type 'InitialState<{ app: AppState; }>'.
    Type '{ app: typeof AppState; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<{ app: AppState; }>'.
    Types of property 'app' are incompatible.
      Property 'app' is missing in type 'typeof AppState' but required in type 'AppState'
    30 initialState: {
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~
     src/app/core/store/crumboard-store.model.ts:139:3
    139   app: {
          ~~~
    'app' is declared here.
    node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts:23:5
    23     initialState?: InitialState<T>;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'initialState' which is declared here on type 
    'RootStoreConfig<{ app: AppState; }, Action>
```

These are my files -
- app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { InitialState } from "@ngrx/store/src/models";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { CrumboardReducer, AppState } from "./core/store";
import { DataStatus } from "./core/store";
```

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    SmgnCoreModule,
    SmgnSharedModule,
    LoginModule,
    PasswordModule,
    DashboardModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(
      {
        app: CrumboardReducer
      },
      {
        initialState: {
          app: {}
        }
      }
    )
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

- crumboard-store.module

```
import { Action, State } from "@ngrx/store";

export class StateItem<T> {
  type: CrumboardActionTypes;
  status: DataStatus;
  data: T;
  error: Error;
```

```
export class AppState {
  app: {
    ACTIVE_PROJECT: StateItem<IApiProject>;
    ACTIVE_TIME_APPROVAL_PROJECT: StateItem<IProjectTimeApprovalTimesheets>;
    ACTIVE_TIMESHEET: StateItem<ITimesheet>;
    ACTIVE_USER: StateItem<User>;
    ASSOCIATED_PROJECTS: StateItem<AssociatedProject[]>;
    CLIENTS: StateItem<IApiClient[]>;
    ESTIMATES: StateItem<IApiEstimateListItem>;
    EXPENSE_CATEGORIES: StateItem<IApiExpenseCategoryItem[]>;
    EXPENSE: StateItem<IApiExpense[]>;
    MARGIN_REPORT: StateItem<IMarginReport>;
    PROJECT_TIMESHEET_SUBMISSIONS: StateItem<IProjectTimeApprovalListItem[]>;
    PROJECTS: StateItem<IApiProjectListItem>;
    QBO_AUTH: StateItem<void>;
    QUICKBOOKS_VENDOR: StateItem<QBOVendor[]>;
    QUICKBOOKS_SERVICE: StateItem<QBOService[]>;
    QUICKBOOKS_EMPLOYEE: StateItem<QBOEmployee[]>;
    QUICKBOOKS_CUSTOMER: StateItem<QBOCustomer[]>;
    QUICKBOOKS_EXPENSE_CATEGORIES: StateItem<QBOExpenseCategory[]>;
    RESOURCE_TYPES: StateItem<ResourceType>;
    TIME_APPROVAL_TEAM_TIMESHEET_LIST: StateItem<TimeApprovalTeamTimesheetList>;
    TIME_APPROVALS: StateItem<IProjectTimeApprovalListItem[]>;
    TIME_TRACKING_REPORT: StateItem<ITimeTrackingReport>;
    UNSUBMITTED_PROJECT_TIMESHEETS: StateItem<IApiTimesheet>;
    UNSUBMITTED_TIMESHEET_EMAIL_REMINDER: StateItem<IApiTimesheet[]>;
    USER_PROJECTS: StateItem<IApiUserProject[]>;
    USERS: StateItem<IApiUserListItem[]>;
  };
}
```

- From ngrx: @ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts
- Finally, my package.json

```
{
  "name": "resourceryweb",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "dev": "ng build --dev --build-optimizer --aot",
    "staging": "ng build -e=staging --build-optimizer --aot",
    "prod": "ng build -e=prod --build-optimizer --aot",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "hmr": "ng serve --hmr -e=hmr"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "9.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "9.0.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/forms": "9.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "9.0.2",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "~1.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "~8.6.0",
    "@types/moment-duration-format": "^2.2.2",
    "core-js": "~2.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "material-design-icons": "~3.0.1",
    "moment": "~2.24.0",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.5.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "9.0.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.28",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "3.7.5"
  }
}
```

It seems like a Type mismatch, but tracing through seems to give me the correct type or perhaps a syntax change that occurred during the change. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you either need `StoreModule.forRoot({ app: CrumboardReducer }, { initialState: {} })` or provide a fuller initialState like `{ app: { ACTIVE_PROJECT: {}, ...}}`. This is typescript issue

Comment: @AndrewAllen so just build out a more verbose app? Since this worked in the past, I figured the app of InitialState was referenced by the app:CrumboardReducer. I will try your suggestion

Comment: that’s a point, try skipping off providing initialState wiithin forRoot altogether given it’s an optional parameter

Comment: have you had any luck?

Comment: no not yet. it allows it compile but the app still breaks. we think its a larger issue related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60383897/hmr-issues-after-update-angular

Comment: @AndrewAllen -- we figured it out. It was a typescript issue like you said, but the issue was located in the AppState class. I will post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was adding a '?' which allows the AppState to be null.

```
export class AppState {
    app?: {
        ACTIVE_PROJECT: StateItem<IApiProject>;
        ACTIVE_TIME_APPROVAL_PROJECT: StateItem<IProjectTimeApprovalTimesheets>;
        ACTIVE_TIMESHEET: StateItem<ITimesheet>;
        ACTIVE_USER: StateItem<User>;
        ASSOCIATED_PROJECTS: StateItem<AssociatedProject[]>;
        CLIENTS: StateItem<IApiClient[]>;
        ESTIMATES: StateItem<IApiEstimateListItem>;
        EXPENSE_CATEGORIES: StateItem<IApiExpenseCategoryItem[]>;
        EXPENSE: StateItem<IApiExpense[]>;
        MARGIN_REPORT: StateItem<IMarginReport>;
        PROJECT_TIMESHEET_SUBMISSIONS: StateItem<IProjectTimeApprovalListItem[]>;
        PROJECTS: StateItem<IApiProjectListItem>;
        QBO_AUTH: StateItem<void>;
        QUICKBOOKS_VENDOR: StateItem<QBOVendor[]>;
        QUICKBOOKS_SERVICE: StateItem<QBOService[]>;
        QUICKBOOKS_EMPLOYEE: StateItem<QBOEmployee[]>;
        QUICKBOOKS_CUSTOMER: StateItem<QBOCustomer[]>;
        QUICKBOOKS_EXPENSE_CATEGORIES: StateItem<QBOExpenseCategory[]>;
        RESOURCE_TYPES: StateItem<ResourceType>;
        TIME_APPROVAL_TEAM_TIMESHEET_LIST: StateItem<TimeApprovalTeamTimesheetList>;
        TIME_APPROVALS: StateItem<IProjectTimeApprovalListItem[]>;
        TIME_TRACKING_REPORT: StateItem<ITimeTrackingReport>;
        UNSUBMITTED_PROJECT_TIMESHEETS: StateItem<IApiTimesheet>;
        UNSUBMITTED_TIMESHEET_EMAIL_REMINDER: StateItem<IApiTimesheet[]>;
        USER_PROJECTS: StateItem<IApiUserProject[]>;
        USERS: StateItem<IApiUserListItem[]>;
      };
    }
```